# Why does the output differs in the given html code?

Tags: html

When i open the html file with the code snippet, mentioned below, in my browser i see a checkbox and a submit button.

```
<form > 
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "q">
    <input type = "submit">
</form>
```

However, when I move the first line along with the form(as shown in the code snippet below) and then reload the file in my browser, I don't see the checkbox. I see only the submit button. 
I infer that mentioning the first line along with form keyword means something different. Can someone explain what is the difference ?

```
<form input type = "checkbox" name = "q">
        <input type = "submit">
</form>
```

PS: I am new to html and web development. This may be a noob question.

Comment: The second one is just not valid HTML. How did you even get there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per definition, the `<form>` tag is used to create an HTML form for user input. This form contains other elements such as `<input>`, `<button>`, `<textarea>`, etc. These elements cannot be clubbed into the `form` tag.

When you write :

```
<form input type = "checkbox" name = "q">
```

it creates an element `form` with attributes `type="checkbox"`, `name="q"` and `input=""` and therefore it doesn't create the checkbox you wanted.

The correct format is :

```
<form>
    <!-- form content -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

A form and an input are two different kinds of elements. You can't just merge them together, it makes no sense. If you want an input, you have to have an input element

For a bit of explanation, when you open a tag like so:

```
<form
```

everything you type within thhat tag before it is closed by a '>' is usually a property of that element. E.g.

```
<form prop1='a' prop2='b'>
  blah blah
</form>
```

Such properties would things like classes or ids. An element can't be a property.